# Wildfly 8.2.0 Final starup script not working Ubuntu 15.05

Tags: ubuntu, wildfly8

After installing the wildfly example debian script in $JBOSS/home, I get the following error when running service wildfly start

"Failed to restart wildfly.service: Unit wildfly.service failed to load: No such file or directory."

I installed the wildfly startup scripts:

```
sudo cp $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-debian.sh/etc/init.d/wildfly
sudo cp $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/init.d/wildfly.conf /etc/default/wildfly
sudo adduser --system --group --disabled-login wildfly
sudo chown -R wildfly:wildfly $WILDFLY_HOME
```

Anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue usually happens when you symlink the start-up script (`$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-debian.sh`). Instead, make a hard link or a plain copy (to `/etc/init.d/wildfly`).

The *"No such file or directory."* is caused by the start-up script not seeing the `pidofproc` and `log_*_msg` functions, although it includes them correctly from `/lib/lsb/init-functions`. You can see this e.g. from `journalctl`.

If you're having this issue even after a plain copy of the start-up script, try to `turn-it-off-and-on-again` (logout from console, or even reboot ;o). But sometimes just `systemctl daemon-reload` is enough.

A [related issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4570) in Jboss issue tracker.